# Can a function and its fourier transform be exponential decay at the same time?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I want to understand the property of a class of real valued function $\mathcal F(\eta,\gamma)$, where $\eta,\gamma$ is positive, and $\forall f \in \mathcal F$
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d} f(x)e^{\eta\|x\|}\mathrm dx< +\infty,\int_{\mathbb R^d}|\hat f(w)|^2 e^{2\gamma ||w||}\mathrm dw <+\infty
$$

My questions:

(1) Is this kind of function exists? If not, how can I relax the assumption to let such kind of function exists (and maybe has the property in (2))

(2) Is it dense in some typical space, like Schwartz Space or L1 Space? (Here maybe you can ignore the influence of $\eta,\gamma$, like I am just want the space to be dense in the $\{f\in L^1:\|f\|_1\leq 1\}$.)

Comment: Gaussian functions will have this property. As for other functions, I have no idea.

Comment: Is not having the square on the first integral intentional? Why not ask that both are square integrable?

Comment: Finite sums of Gaussians are dense in the Schwartz space and $L^p$ and many other spaces, simply approximate $f\in L^1$ by $\sum_{n=-N^2}^{N^2} 
N^{1/2}e^{-\pi N(x-n/N)^2}  \int_{n/N}^{(n+1)/N} f(t)dt$

Comment: Thanks for Hudgins and reuns! it really helps!

Comment: @reuns I'm a litted bit confused about your construction. What will it be like when $f \in L^1(\mathbb R^d) (d>=3)$? Thanks!